# set vim python indent space based on file

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I know it is possible to set the indent for a specific filetype by

```
set softtabstop=4
```

But the problem I am facing is, I have different python script files, some of them are indented with 2 spaces, while some of them are indented with 4 spaces. Is it possible to let vim determine the indent spaces to use (2 or 4) automatically based on the file opened?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can do this using some plugins. See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/52) for example

Comment: @Teoretic Thanks. I found vim-sleuth from that post works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this vim plugin will do what you want: https://github.com/requalix/detect-indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that can detect the used indent settings. Some, like my [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) also warn you about inconsistent indents. The following list is taken from my plugin's documentation:

- My own [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690); automatic triggering is enabled by the companion [IndentConsistencyCopAutoCmds plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1691).
- Indent Finder ([vimscript #513](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=513)) is a Python script and Vim plugin that scans
  any loaded buffer and configures the appropriate indent settings
- yaifa.vim ([vimscript #3096](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096)) is a port to vimscript of the above
- detectindent.vim (https://github.com/ciaranm/detectindent) by Ciaran
  McCreesh tries to auto-detect the indentation settings
- GuessIndent ([vimscript #4251](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4251)) is based on detectindent.vim
- indentdetect.vim
  (https://github.com/ervandew/vimfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/indentdetect.vim)
  by Eric Van Dewoestine performs a simple detection and can set defaults
  based on the filespec
- matchindent.vim ([vimscript #4066](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4066)) detects tabs, 2 and 4-space indents and
  adapts the indent settings accordingly
- sleuth.vim ([vimscript #4375](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4375)) by Tim Pope automatically adjusts 'shiftwidth'
  and 'tabstop' heuristically (via a simplistic sampling that does not check
  for bad or inconsistent indents) or by looking at other files of the same
  type
- filestyle ([vimscript #5065](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5065)) highlights tabs when 'expandtab' is set,
  trailing spaces, and lines longer than 'textwidth', but doesn't actually
  check conformance to indent
- ShowSpaces ([vimscript #5148](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5148)) highlights spaces inside indentation, per
  buffer / filetype.
- Indent Detector ([vimscript #5195](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5195)) run when a file is opened or written, has
  warnings about mixed tab / space indent, and can adapt Vim's corresponding
  options automatically.